# Rerendering application causing creating two instances of redux store

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have react-redux application which is a modal. And I need to toggle it from outside. My initial app looked like this:

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { applyMiddleware, compose, createStore } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

import App from './lib/containers/App';

import reducer from './lib/ducks/reducers';

import MY_PROPTYPES from './lib/proptypes';

/* eslint-disable no-underscore-dangle */
const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__
  || compose;
/* eslint-enable */
const middleware = [];
middleware.push(thunk);

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
  // eslint-disable-next-line global-require
  const { createLogger } = require('redux-logger');
  middleware.push(createLogger());
}

export default class Gallery extends PureComponent {
 render() {


    const initState = {
     ...
    };

   const store = createStore(
        reducer,
        initState,
        composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(...middleware))

    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <App
          onClose={e => onClose(e)}
          isVisible={isVisible}
          initialPosition={initialPosition}
        />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

This was causing me problems when I close modal and open it. It stops rerendering although store changes. So store changes accordingly, but my App is not reacting to these changes.
I found out that was because I create different instance of my store and pass it to my app again, but it's still connected to previous store.

So, I changed my entry point:
I added constructor with store in state, and I changed creating store to this code:

```
 let newStore = store;
    if (!newStore) {
      newStore = createStore(
        reducer,
        initState,
        composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(...middleware))
      );
      this.setState({ store: newStore });
    }
```

And this newStore I pass to my Provider. This solved my problem and App is changing according to store, but now I have this JS error:

> Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as
>   within `render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props
>   and state.

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "@fishingbooker/gallery",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "./dist",
  "directories": {
    "doc": "docs"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "lib": "babel src -d dist",
    "lib:watch": "babel src -w -d dist",
    "docs": "webpack-dev-server --open",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --open --mode development --host 0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check --https",
    "docs:prof": "webpack -p"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.1.2",
    "@babel/core": "^7.1.2",
    "@babel/helper-plugin-utils": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.2.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/register": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.4",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "webpack": "^4.20.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.9"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fishingbooker/react-slick": "0.0.5",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "mousetrap": "^1.6.2",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
    "react": "^16.5.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.5.2",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.0",
    "react-swipe": "^6.0.3",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  }
}
```

Does anybody knows how can I fix this error, or how to rerender my entry point so my App stays connected to store.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show your code after you put store creation in the constructor

Comment: It's the same, just setting the store to state if it doesn't exist.  And there is piece of code in my question that shows that:


let newStore = store;
    if (!newStore) {
      newStore = createStore(
        reducer,
        initState,
        composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(...middleware))
      );
      this.setState({ store: newStore });
    }

Comment: You are supposed to create store only once. Check out example over here https://redux.js.org/basics/example

Comment: @SLCH000 I do create store only once. And I save it to state. When it's saved I read it from the state. And then the error above occurs.

Comment: Which component shows this error? Also in constructor you set state with `this.state = {{store: newStore}}` https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-local-state-to-a-class And did i get that right, you removed store creation in `render()` method?

Comment: Initially store is null so I set it as:

`this.state = {
      store: null
    };`

Comment: My main component - entry point of my application.

I do have store creation with condition. If my store from state is null, I create it. But if it's not null - I use it from . my state

Comment: Sorry but putting the redux store inside the component store in not the way to go with redux